# Get name of field being passed

Tags: javascript

I have two sets of lists (state lists)
One called state_o and one called state_d and I have a function I do on them

```
function selectCountry(sel) {
    document.getElementById("country_o").selectedIndex = states[sel.value];
}
```

Now what I want to do is determine if the "sel" is state_o or state_d and change the getElementById("country_o") to either _o or _d depending on what state is selected, so state_o would do country_o and state_d would do country_d

How can I determine the select field name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the name property through javascript:

```
function selectCountry(sel) {
    var od = sel.name == "state_o" ? "o" : "d";
    document.getElementById("country_"+od).selectedIndex = states[sel.value];
}
```

Or if you want to be a bit fancier and keep it on one line, slice the o/d straight from the name string:

```
function selectCountry(sel) {
    document.getElementById("country_"+sel.name.slice(-1)).selectedIndex = states[sel.value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep another parameter in this function to see if its _o or _d and set this value in calling function.
then in your javascript method you can call country by -

```
document.getElementById("country" + param2)
```

Assuming param2 is that additional parameter and it will contain string "_o" or "_d"

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right, it's just:

```
var field;
if (sel.value == 'state_o')
    field = 'country_o';
else
    field = 'country_d';

document.getElementById(field).selectedIndex = states[sel.value];
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sel` is the select element, `sel.id` or `sel.name` should give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sel.attr('name')` if you're using jQuery or `sel.name` if just using plain old Javascript

Assuming you have:

```
<SELECT name='state_o'>
  <OPTION value='blah'>BLAH</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<SELECT name='state_d'>
  <OPTION value='blah'>BLAH</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: *attr()* isn't a valid function on any DOM object.

Comment: $(sel),attr("name") should do it